# Blazor onchange event not working in inputselect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Here I am using blazor server app  to populate city dropdownList in Change of country dropdownlist. Here I have made `CustomInputSelect` to avoid error `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputSelect`1[System.Int32] does not support the type 'System.Int32'`.
But the problem is that onchange event doesnot trigger and does not hit the countyClicked method as result the city dropdown doenot get populated according to change in country dropdown.
Below is my razor component html with custom inputselect

```
<EditForm Model="@PersonModel"  OnValidSubmit="postPerson">
         <CustomInputSelect @bind-Value="PersonModel.CountryId"  class="form-control"  @onchange="countyClicked">
            <option value="">Select country</option>
            @foreach (var item in Countries)
            {
                <option value="@item.CountryId">@item.CountryName</option>
            }
        </CustomInputSelect>
        <CustomInputSelect class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" @bind-Value="PersonModel.CityId">
            @foreach (var city in Cities)
            {
                <option value="@city.CityId">@city.CityName</option>
            }
        </CustomInputSelect>
</EditForm>
```

Below is my countyClicked method

```
    public void countyClicked(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var getCountryId = args.Value.ToString();
        int.TryParse(getCountryId, out int countryId);
        Cities = mainService.GetAllCityByCountryId(countryId);
    }
```

Below is my CustomInputSelect

```
    public class CustomInputSelect<TValue> : InputSelect<TValue>
{
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result,
        out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(value, out var resultInt))
            {
                result = (TValue)(object)resultInt;
                validationErrorMessage = null;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = default;
                validationErrorMessage =
                    $"The selected value {value} is not a valid number.";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result,
                out validationErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to Net5.0... InputSelect supports int and enum types...

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the `InputSelect` code you'll see that `onchanged` doesn't get called when the value changes.

The solution to your problem is to set up your model property to fire an event when it's set.  You then wire up `CountryChanged` to that event.

```cs
    // Declare a delegate
    public delegate void SelectChanged(int value);

    class model
    {

        public int CountryId
        {
            get => _CountryId;
            set
            {
                _CountryId = value;
                CountryChanged.Invoke(value);
            }
        }

        private int _CountryId;

        public SelectChanged CountryChanged;
    }
```

Wire up the event in your page

```
@implements IDisposable
```

```
   protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editcontext = new EditContext(mymodel);
        mymodel.CountryChanged += CountryChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        mymodel.CountryChanged -= CountryChanged;
    }
```

You may need to get a bit fancier on the wiring and unwiring of the event depending on how you get your model.